# How to solve such complicated integration involving product of two lower incomplete Gamma function?

Tags: definite-integrals, gamma-function, hypergeometric-function

I am trying to solve the following integration but not getting it correctly.

$$P = \int_0^\infty \left(\gamma\left(1+b,\frac{t(1+x)-1}{A\sigma^2_1}\right)\right)^N\cdot\frac{\exp\left(\frac{-x}{A_1\sigma^2_5}\right)\left(\frac x{A_1\sigma^2_5}\right)^b\gamma\left(1+b,\frac{x}{A_1\sigma^2_5}\right)^{M-1}}{A_1\sigma^2_5}\text{d}x$$

where $\gamma(\cdot,\cdot)$ is lower incomplete Gamma function, $x$ is variable of integration and all other things are constant.

Using change of variable, I obtained the following simplified equation but not getting how to proceed further.

$$P = \int_0^\infty \underbrace{\left(\gamma\left(1+b,\frac{t(1+A_1\sigma^2_5y)-1}{A\sigma^2_1}\right)\right)^N}_{P_1}\cdot\underbrace{{\exp\left(-y\right)\cdot y^b\cdot \gamma\left(1+b,y\right)^{M-1}}}_{P_2}\text{d}y$$

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can we take out $\frac{1}{A_1\sigma^2_5}$ outside of lower incomplete Gamma function?

Comment: It looks like you replaced your comment. You can factor those since they are constants with respect to $x$. If you want to get rid of the constants in the argument of the incomplete gamma function, then you can do a change of variables with $\frac{x}{A_1\sigma^2_5}=y$ or $\frac{t(1+x)-1}{A\sigma^2_1}=y$ etc for a similar effect.

Comment: Ok. Basically I tried taking out constants but got stuck as the $\frac{1}{A_1\sigma^2_5}$ is inside lower incomplete Gamma function. Now will try with change of variable method.

Comment: Can we simultaneously do change of variables for both lower incomplete Gamma function? i.e., can we write like $\frac{x}{A_1\sigma^2_5} = y$ and  $\frac{t(1+x)-1}{A\sigma^2_1} = y$ simultaneously ?

Comment: We cannot, but you can apply one after the other. Try with one first since one just simplifies the integrand. Can you edit the question with your findings so that it is updated and more people can see it?

Comment: Ok. Will update my question also.

Comment: I had obtained new expression after change of variable. However its $P_1$ has $x$ variable and $P_2$ has $y$ variable. So how to proceed from this step?

Comment: Any suggestion or hint will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can we say there is no way to solve the above integration?

Comment: The incomplete gamma function could be expanded as a sum or integral, but the “M”th power would make the expression too complicated. However, there is [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4239879/integral-of-multiple-incomplete-gamma-functions), so there may be a method that was not mentioned yet to solve your problem. Maybe ask the answerer of the question?

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. Will try to explore it.